# uncaughtException "Cannot read property 'info' of undefined" Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, logging

I am trying to add an interceptor in my main config file,below is the code.But I am getting the above error after adding the log. Googled but didn't get much help.Kindly help if anyone faced this error before.

```
 // Intercept http calls.
$provide.factory('HttpResponseInterceptor', ['$q', '$log', function ($q, $log) {
    return {
        // On request success
        request: function (config) {
            $log.info('HttpInterceptor Request object' + config); // Contains the data about the request before it is sent.

            // Return the config or wrap it in a promise if blank.
            return config || $q.when(config);
        },

        // On request failure
        requestError: function (rejection) {
            $log.error('HttpInterceptor Request Failure' + rejection); // Contains the data about the error on the request.

            // Return the promise rejection.
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        },

        // On response success
        response: function (response) {
            $log.info('HttpInterceptor Success Response' + response); // Contains the data from the response.

            // Return the response or promise.
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },

        // On response failture
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            $log.error('HttpInterceptor Response Failure' + rejection); // Contains the data about the error.

            // Return the promise rejection.
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
}]);

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpResponseInterceptor');
```

Comment: add a plunker so we can diagnose.

Comment: @Jones : After restarting using "gulp serve" it worked....logs are printing...Thanks